# Trace Class - How to set Autoflush by code

Tags: c#, trace, system.diagnostics

I would like to set the AutoFlush attribute to true, but I need to do it by code.  Programmatically.

I have found this [how to configure the trace element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe8whywc.aspx) and also the [AutoFlush property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.autoflush%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the Trace Class.

Then I have this code to get the TraceSource:

```
private static TraceSource GetTraceSource()
{
    var ts = new TraceSource("TraceManager")
        {
            Switch =
                {
                    Level = SourceLevels.All
                }
        };
    ts.Attributes.Add("AutoFlush", "true");
    ts.Listeners.Remove("Default");

    var file = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + @"\MyApplication.log";
    var textListener = new TextWriterTraceListener(file)
        {
            Filter = new EventTypeFilter(SourceLevels.All)
        };

    ts.Listeners.Add(textListener);
    return ts;
}
```

How can I set the AutoFlush property to true inside this code ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding this...

```
Trace.AutoFlush = true;
```

Comment: Hi @Paul, but Trace is not a static class... is it ? :-O

Comment: Correct but all of its properties and methods are static so no instance is needed to be referenced. The same applies to Trace.WriteLine and other methods.

Comment: Opps.  I hadn't seen the class methods.  :-\  Thanks again.